# Send mail trough TELNET over OVH with .batch script

Tags: powershell

I would like to use TELNET to send an email with the content of `log.txt` using one of my OVH mail accounts (noreply@clement.business hosted on OVH) to a gmail address. Due to my society security politics I am not able to install anything on the servers but the OS itself.

So I tried with both batch and PowerShell but without success, I even tried manually, I can telnet OVH but then don't know how to login.

Here's a few things I tried :

```
$subject = $args[0]

# Create from/to addresses
$from = New-Object system.net.mail.MailAddress "noreply@clement.business"
$to = New-Object system.net.mail.MailAddress "random@gmail.com"

# Create Message
$message = new-object system.net.mail.MailMessage $from, $to
$message.Subject = $subject
$message.Body = @"
Am I even suppose to write here
"@

# Set SMTP Server and create SMTP Client
$server = "I have no idea how to OVH here"
$client = new-object system.net.mail.smtpclient $server... Server what, POP3 ?

# Do
"Sending an e-mail message to {0} by using SMTP host {1} port {2}." -f $to.ToString(), $client.Host, $client.Port
try {
$client.Send($message)
}
catch {
"Exception caught in CreateTestMessage: {0}" -f $Error.ToString()
}
```

I cannot figure that out, it is such a struggle to deal with...

PS : I did use the [OVH guide](https://docs.ovh.com/fr/fr/web/emails/mail-mutualise-guide-configuration-dun-e-mail-mutualise-ovh-sur-linterface-de-gmail/) about POP3/SMTP setup, but did not work, or I have no idea what I am doing. [Useful link here as well](https://www.pantz.org/software/pop3/pop3telnet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know the difference: POP3 is used to receive email, SMTP is used to send email. You can't use them interchangeably.

A quick google for 'ovh smtp server' shows that the ovh [help pages](http://help.ovh.co.uk/EmailConfiguration) list the SMTP servers as:

```
Server name: ns0.ovh.net
Port of the outgoing server: 587
Username: identical to the email address
Password: your password for your account, as defined in the creation of the email address
```

I can't test these as I don't have an ovh account.

I would use `Send-MailMessage` to send the email as it's much easier to use than your solution:'

This will send an email with the file `log.txt` as an attachment:

```
$username = "noreply@clement.business"
$password = "passwordforemailaddress" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password

$parms = @{
    From = "noreply@clement.business"
    To = "email@gmail.com"
    Attachment = "C:\folder\log.txt"
    Subject = "Daily Logs"
    Body = "Your body text here"
    SMTPServer = "ns0.ovh.net"
    SMTPPort = "587"
    Credential = $credentials
}
Send-MailMessage @params
```

And these params this will use `log.txt` as the email body text:

```
$parms = @{
    From = "noreply@clement.business"
    To = "email@gmail.com"
    Body = Get-Content "C:\folder\log.txt"
    Subject = "Daily Logs"
    SMTPServer = "ns0.ovh.net"
    SMTPPort = "587"
    Credential = $credentials
}
```